# Integrating multivariate densities with variable bounds.

Tags: multivariable-calculus, probability-distributions, density-function, multiple-integral

I am struggling how to deal with certain bounds when it comes to integrating multivariate densities.

How would you specify the bounds to integrate a function such as
$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x,y)  \,dx\,dy$ with bounds like

(i) $0<x<y<2$

(ii) $0<x<1$, $0<y<\sqrt(x)$

I don't know whether these examples make sense, I just made them up to go one step further from what we did in class. I know how to deal with for example $0<x$, $0<y$, $x+y<1$, but as soon as the bounds get more complex I fail to understand how to approach it. Is there a general method to go about more complex bounds as I have outlined above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be precise, what you mean is to find a double integral of the form
$$
\iint_D f(x,y)dxdy
$$
where $D$ is a region defined by inequalities or to find $$
\iint_{\mathbb{R}^2} f(x,y)dxdy
$$
where $f$ is "supported" on the region $D$.

For those integrals that can be calculated by hand, your goal is to write it as iterated integrals. To figure out the bounds, drawing a picture would be helpful. See below for your examples.

How to find the bounds should be a very standard materials you see in a textbook when you learn double integrals the first time.

In general, the "easy" integrals can be written as one of the following ways:
$$
\int_a^b\left(\int_{c(x)}^{d(x)}f(x,y)dy\right)dy,\quad
\int_a^b\left(\int_{c(y)}^{d(y)}f(x,y)dx\right)dy \tag{1}
$$

So if the region $ D$ has been written in one of the following forms:
$$
D=\{(x,y): c(x)<y<d(x), a<x<b\},\quad D=\{(x,y): c(y)<x<d(y), a<y<b\}
$$
you should be happy since it tells you directly the bounds in (1).

Your third example,
$$
x>0,\quad y>0,\quad x+y<1
$$
can be written as
$$
D=\{(x,y): 0<y<1-x, 0<x<1\}
$$
or
$$
D=\{(x,y): 0<y<1, 0<x<1-y\}
$$

---

[image]  [image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot for this. Trying to visualise the bounds really helps to understand what to integrate. I came up with one more issue: what if both variable bounds are mutually dependent, i.e. $0 < x < \sqrt(y)$ and $0 < y < \sqrt(x)$? If I try to draw $\sqrt(x)$ and $\sqrt(y)$ in a graph to find the bounds they somehow intersect?

Comment: @Luca: in your example, you can find the intersections and write the region in the form of $D=\{(x,y): 0<x<1, c(x)<y<c(x)\}$. It is a good exercise to figure out what those functions are.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. So the intersection must be at 1, since this is the only place where $\sqrt(x) = x^2$ holds. Say we now integrate, as you say, $0 < x < 1$, we still can't just integrate $0 < y < \sqrt(y)$, as we need the lense-shaped area between the two curves if I'm not mistaken. Usually with such an area, you have to subtract the curve "below" from the curve "above", so the only bound I could imagine would be something like $\sqrt(x) > y > x^2$, but that does not feel right to me...

Comment: @Luca: that is actually correct. The constraints $0<x<\sqrt{y}$ and $0<y<\sqrt{x}$ are the same as $0<x<1$ and $x^2<y<\sqrt{x}$.

Comment: Oh perfect then, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Presumably you are trying to handle $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x,y)  \,dx\,dy$ where you know $f(x,y)=0$ outside the bounds.  A sensible way to approach this is with indicator functions, but sometimes the answer is sufficiently clear anyway.

In your two particular examples:

(i) $0<x<y<2$ can be $$\int_{y=0}^{2}\int_{x=0}^{y} f(x,y)  \,dx\,dx$$ or equivalently $$\int_{x=0}^{2}\int_{y=x}^{2} f(x,y)  \,dy\,dx$$

(ii) $0<x<1$, $0<y<\sqrt x$ can be $$\int_{x=0}^{1}\int_{y=0}^{\sqrt x} f(x,y)  \,dy\,dx$$